# Unable To Concatenate 2 Linux Variables Into 1

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I'm trying to concatenate two variables in linux tectia SSH into one variable, separated by `"_"`. For some reason only one of the two variables is printed out.

I've tried to concatenate via `" "` e.g.:

```
sample1="$var1_$var2"
```

or

```
sample1="$var1 _ $var2"
```

and I've tried to concatenate directly e.g.:

```
sample1=$var1_$var2
```

Would appreciate any help given!

```
cnt_abr1=ab
cnt_abr2=cd
cnt_abr3=ef
env_abr1=a
env_abr2=b
sample1="$env_abr1_$cnt_abr1"
sample2=$env_abr2_$cnt_abr3
echo $sample1
echo $sample2
```

Output:

```
 _ ab
ef
```

Comment: There is no such variable as `$env_abr1_` (note the training underscore)

Comment: oh i see. Is there a way to concatenate $env_abr1 and $cnt_abr1 by an underscore with no spaces?

Comment: Please fix your output: https://ideone.com/4kxGA0

Comment: Ironically enough, all your examples would work besides the final mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since underscores are effectively letters, bash has no way of knowing when your variable name ends and your literal underscore begins. The proper way to reference the variables is with `${...}` in this case, which unambiguously delimits the name from the rest of the command line:

```
sample1="${env_abr1}_${cnt_abr1}"
sample2=${env_abr2}_${cnt_abr3}
```

In both cases, the second name does not require special treatment. Any other (semantically valid) non-letter character would do as well, as you pointed out in your comment:

```
sample1="$env_abr1"_"$cnt_abr1"
sample2="$env_abr2"_"$cnt_abr3"
```

Comment: Great! This works. I found another way too which was sample1="$env_abr1"_"$cnt_abr1"